# Scheduled / Recurring Apex Within A Week

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, developer-console

*I am not finding this anywhere in Help at Salesforce or via Google.*

WHen I **schedule Apex via the Developer's Console** (a weekly run), is it NOT possible to have the first run in LESS than a WEEK?

```
Cls_BatchCreateOpportHistryWeeklySchd OppOwner_Weekly = new Cls_BatchCreateOpportHistryWeeklySchd ();
String schWeek = '0 30 2 ? * SUN'; // Every Sunday 
String jobIDW = system.schedule('WEEKLY Opp Owner History', schWeek, OppOwner_Weekly);
```

This was instantiated on 3/2/2015 at 8am.  The first scheduled run, no matter how I delete and retry, is for 3/15 (instead of 3/8, just under six days from 3/2).

So, I actually need to set a reminder to me to manually run this one time, or..?

Thanks.

Comment: So your issue is that you are trying to get your job to run for `0 30 2 ? * SUN`, which should be **every Sunday at 2:30am**, but when you run it on Monday March 2nd it is skipping Sunday March 8th and starting on Sunday March 15th instead?

Comment: Yes that (was) the case.   Not the end of the world (though I DID forget to set a reminder for myself, so...).   Anyway.

Comment: It sounds like a bug with SalesForce. You may want to raise a case with them. I tend to allow my schedulable class to have a date passed into it, ie the execution date. The code will use the execution date rather than Date.today() when running the job. This means if you ever forget to run a job you can execute it with the correct date passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about this ; but no need to set reminder. 
One alternate is to schedule it for next sunday by setting 'day of the month' 
Your string could be :
String schday = '0 30 2 8 3 ? SUN';

Comment: Joyously... I did not even set the reminder for myself, so I ran it the first time a day late. Good job, numb nut, I literally said out loud.    Thanks in any case.